# Laravel Nova API - Can you apply a filter to a requested resource or lens

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Is it possible (or has anyone found a way) to apply a filter when getting a lens via the API, ie;

http://my-site.test/nova-api/my-model/lens/my-lens?filter=MyFilter

The ability to add multiple filters would be cool too if anyone knows how

Comment: your quention is not cleared what you want to do exactly. Can you please explain little bit more

Comment: If you open a project with laravel nova and go to the address `localhost/nova-api/my-model/lens/my-lens` (obviously putting in a valid model/lens) you get a json response of the data, what I want to do is apply a nova filter to that resource. If you don't have experience with laravel nova (which I assume you don't) then you probably can't help :(

Comment: yes you are right i am not having experience in nova

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I worked out how to do it, the filters are passed through after being base64 encoded in `$request->filters`, example;

```
[
    {"class":"App\\Nova\\Filters\\MyFilter","value":1}
]
```

Let's say this is your  "filters" payload, you base64 encode it;

`Ww0KICAgICAgICB7ImNsYXNzIjoiQXBwXFxOb3ZhXFxGaWx0ZXJzXFxNeUZpbHRlciIsInZhbHVlIjoxfQ0KICAgIF0=`

Then the URL you would pass through would be;

`http://my-site.test/nova-api/my-model/lens/my-lens?filters=Ww0KICAgICAgICB7ImNsYXNzIjoiQXBwXFxOb3ZhXFxGaWx0ZXJzXFxNeUZpbHRlciIsInZhbHVlIjoxfQ0KICAgIF0=`

Comment: Did you figure out how to generate one via route() or url()?

Comment: @Citizen No, but we ended up using several of [beyondcode](https://github.com/beyondcode)'s packages for Nova which added quite a lot of useful functionality not available out of the box. Perhaps you'll find them as useful as we did.

Answer (score 1):

```php
private function filterize($id)
{
    $filter = base64_encode('[{"class":"App\\\\Nova\\\\Filters\\\\Ticket","value":"'.$id.'"}]');
    return trim($filter);
}
```

Then just use

```html
http://my-site.test/nova-api/my-model/lens/my-lens?filter={!! filterized_value !!}
```